# How to store non-english characters?

Tags: mysql

Non-english characters are messed up in a text column. Arabic text looks like this:

> Ù†Ù€Ø¬Ù€Ù… Ø³Ù€Ù‡Ù€ÙŠÙ€Ù„

How to store non-english characters correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should consider using **utf8** to store your text.

You can do this at the database creation:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydb
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8
  DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

You can also configure mysql at installation or at startup to use utf8 (see [Mysql manual)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-applications.html)

The mysql manual pages cover all aspects of characterset and collations: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html

The character set of the connection can be changed by

```
SET CHARACTER SET utf8
```

More details [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html) and in the chapter [*Character set support*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset.html)

Answer (score 2):

What OS are you using?

If Linux then it's good to have a system locale set to utf8 also, like "en_US.utf8".

And, to be sure, issue an "SET NAMES UTF8" command to mysql just after connection.

(db character set/collation must also be utf8)

Answer (score 2):

The query below solved the issue.

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: And for the whole database if possible would be even better. 
Use SET NAMES utf8