# Can't store non-english name in mysql table properly

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, web-scraping

I'm trying to store some fields derived from a webpage in mysql table. The script that I've created can parse the data and store them in the table. However, as the username is non-english, the table stores the name as `????????? ?????????` instead of `Αθανάσιος Σουλιώτης`.

Script I've tried with:

```
import mysql.connector
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941060/web-scraper-update'

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd = "",
  database="mydatabase",
  charset='utf8',
  use_unicode=True
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists webdata")
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists webdata (title VARCHAR(255), username VARCHAR(255), reputation VARCHAR(255))")

response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
post_title = soup.select_one("h1[itemprop='name'] > a").get_text(strip=True)
username = soup.select_one(".user-details > a").get_text(strip=True)
reputation = soup.select_one("span.reputation-score").get_text(strip=True)

print((post_title,username,reputation))

mycursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO webdata (title,username,reputation) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",
    (post_title,username,reputation)
)

mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

This is how the output are being printed in the console:

```
('Web scraper update', 'Αθανάσιος Σουλιώτης', '13')
```

The database stores the output as:

```
'Web scraper update', '????????? ?????????', '13'
```

> How can I store non-english name in mysql table accordingly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008918/how-to-store-non-english-characters Hope it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this and try again.

I added the commit on a new 3 lines.

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(

host="localhost",
  user="root",
  passwd = "",
  database="mydatabase",
  charset='utf8',
  use_unicode=True
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

// add below line 1)
mycursor.execute("ALTER DATABASE `%s` CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'" % 'mydatabase')

mycursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists webdata")
mycursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists webdata (title VARCHAR(255), username VARCHAR(255), reputation VARCHAR(255))")

mycursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')             // <--- add this line   2)
mycursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')  // <--- add this line   3)

response = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")
```

I have already tested it.

Please make a commit after check.

Comment: Thanks for your solution @Victory. How can I implement this within my existing script?

Answer (score 0):

θ symbol is 2-byte size with `UTF-8` ( *0xCE 0x98* ).
I am not sure but `UTF-16` can solve this( *0x0398* ).